Does pods in Kubernetes node split the existing bandwidth based on any specific criteria?
I have multiple pods running on a single K8s node. I'm using AWS EKS cluster. Earlier I was using bigger machines for node group so that we can reduce the resources (cpu/memory) consumed by daemonset pods. Our application usecase require a lot of data download from pod.
In this case, as we were using bigger machines (eg: 128GB RAM machines) and it can accommodate more number of pods. We noticed that, as more number of pods utilizing the existing machine bandwidth, the per pod download speed is very less.
We changed the node type to 64GB RAM machine and noticed that the per pod bandwidth, increased. Currently we are running on 32GB RAM machine (node).
I want to figure out that, is there any specific criteria for bandwidth sharing among pods?
For example, a single machine has 1000MBPS bandwidth and it has 10 pods running inside it, each pod will get 100MBps or if one pod starts downloading first and if it is getting 500MBps, and when the remaining starts downloading only the remaining bandwidth get split?
I know my question is a bit indirect or may be basics on the networking side that I am not aware of. Please shed some lights on it. Or any pointers to K8s networking regarding this query would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

For example, a single machine has 1000MBPS bandwidth and it has 10 pods running inside it, each pod will get 100MBps or if one pod starts downloading first and if it is getting 500MBps, and when the remaining starts downloading only the remaining bandwidth get split?
Since the traffic split between pods is managed by K8s service (since you are downloading data I am guessing it is of type Load Balancer), the logic for bandwidth distribution follows the same analogy as of devices connected to a router. The pod that starts downloading first will start with more bandwidth and it will gradually decrease as more and more pods start downloading.
Regarding your observation about seeing different bandwidths with different types of nodes, it is difficult to answer the question as the node itself can be on a bare-metal or on a VM. And the behaviour of network split will vary greatly with this. Will be happy to explain more on this if needed.
